# How should I fill the holes where my curtain rod was, so that I can reuse them?

Tags: walls, brick, curtain-rail

My curtain rail has fallen down and the holes are too big to plug and re-use. What is the best products/method to fill the deep holes and hang my curtain rails?

Please note:

1. Curtain rails are wooden.
2. I need to hang in the same place, as this is rented property.
3. Brick walls.

For clarity here is the hole:

[image]

Screw and plug:

[image]

How it should look:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with my curtains.  I was able to use the Tapcon concrete 3/16” by 2-1/4” concrete anchors.

If your holes are too large for the Tapcons: try drilling out the hole to a ½ inch in diameter and about two inches deep.  Then add some construction glue and pound in a ½ inch dowel.  You can then reattach the curtain hangers with wood screws.

Comment: I think the inserted wooden plug idea is going to be the best strategy here. Since the curtain holder already has a integral screw it is not going to be feasible to use some other type of fastener. Before pounding in the dowel do blow out all of the dust and debris in the hole. Also do not get carried away with excess amounts of the construction adhesive as it can get behind the dowel and keep you from being able to pound in as far as you want. (You can cut off excess dowel length flush with the wall surface). Also make sure to drill a pilot hole for the screw into (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) the dowel before reinstalling the curtain rod holder. Unless the dowel is a really tight fit you will want to wait some time for the adhesive to set up before trying to drill or screw into the dowel.

Comment: Those plastic anchors (in the pics) don't last/work. I haven't had one of them hold up in the 20+ years that I've owned my house.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your screw is integral to the bracket so a larger screw is not an option... I think I would use a larger plug that fits snugly in the hole (either plastic or lead), then break off a couple of wooden match sticks in it so the bracket screw grips relatively well. Then coach whoever pulled too hard on the curtain! LOL.